# Windows make all files in folder that contain a line read-only

Tags: windows, windows-10, batch-file, read-only, findstr

I have some files in a directory with the comment:

```
// _READONLY_
```

I'd like to set all these files to read-only using a batch script.

I've found this command to set read-only status:

```
attrib +r
```

I know that there's a `findstr` command, but I'm struggling to string (pun intended :) the two together to do what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a ***command line and a batch script*** example using a [FOR /F](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) loop to set the read-only attribute for all `.txt` files in a single directory with the matching `"// _READONLY_"` string.

**A few things to mention here are...**

- The `FOR /F` options block uses `:` as the delimiter to split on that value per iteration
- The `FOR /F` options block uses `1` and `2` tokens to get value before each `:` value per iteration—so the drive letter with no proceeding colon and the full file path with no preceding colon minus the drive letter—to be used as `%a` and `%b` in these examples
- The `FOR /F` command-parameter block puts a colon `:` between the first and second token values to create the file path again since it was split on the colon and it's omitted otherwise

  - This is how the `attrib +r` command can process each matching file where it will concatenate the `%a` value, colon, and `%b` with no spaces between (e.g. `%a:%b`)
- Throw a `FOR /R` in the mix and pass each of the recursive subdirectory value to a proceeding `FOR /F` command to search all of them for `.txt` files containing a matching string

  > **A bug with recursive `FINDSTR` and one which `FOR /R` mitigates...**
  >
  > <sub>`FINDSTR` ought to be able to recurse a directory tree with the `/S`
  > option. But there is a nasty bug that can cause some files to be
  > skipped if your filesystem has short names enabled. See [What are the
  > undocumented features and limitations of the Windows FINDSTR
  > command?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8844873/1012053) for more info.
  > Look for the *section* header "**BUG - Short 8.3 filenames can break the
  > /D and /S option**s" *within that answer.* –
  > [dbenham](https://superuser.com/users/109090/dbenham)</sub>

#### Command Line

**Note:** The first line command `FOR /F` is to get all parent level folder files. The second line command `FOR /R` is to get all beneath subfolders and their files plus the parent folder.

```
FOR /F "DELIMS=: TOKENS=1,2" %a IN ('findstr C:"// _READONLY_" "C:\Folder\Path\*.txt"') DO attrib +r "%a:%b"
FOR /R "C:\Folder\Path\" %D IN (.) DO (FOR /F "DELIMS=: TOKENS=1,2" %a IN ('findstr C:"// _READONLY_" "%~fdD\*.txt"') DO (attrib +r "%~a:%~b"))
```

#### Batch Script

**Note:** Double up the percent signs `%%` in batch script with `FOR` loop variable placeholders `%%a` and `%%b`—so for a command line to run as a batch script is usually that simple with `FOR` loops.

```
FOR /F "DELIMS=: TOKENS=1,2" %%a IN ('findstr C:"// _READONLY_" "C:\Folder\Path\*.txt"') DO attrib +r "%%a:%%b"
FOR /R "C:\Folder\Path\" %%D IN (.) DO (
    FOR /F "DELIMS=: TOKENS=1,2" %%a IN ('findstr C:"// _READONLY_" "%%~fdD\*.txt"') DO (
        attrib +r "%%~a:%%~b"))
```

---

#### Supporting Resources

- [FOR /F](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- [FOR /R](https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html)
- `FOR /?`

  > ```
  > FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN (`command`) DO command [command-parameters]
  >
  >
  >     delims=xxx      - specifies a delimiter set.  This replaces the
  >                       default delimiter set of space and tab.
  >     tokens=x,y,m-n  - specifies which tokens from each line are to
  >                       be passed to the for body for each iteration.
  >                       This will cause additional variable names to
  >                       be allocated.  The m-n form is a range,
  >                       specifying the mth through the nth tokens.  If
  >                       the last character in the tokens= string is an
  >                       asterisk, then an additional variable is
  >                       allocated and receives the remaining text on
  >                       the line after the last token parsed.
  >
  > In addition, substitution of FOR variable references has been
  > enhanced. You can now use the following optional syntax:
  >
  > %~I         - expands %I removing any surrounding quotes (")
  > %~fI        - expands %I to a fully qualified path name
  > %~dI        - expands %I to a drive letter only
  > ```
- `Findstr /?`

  > ```
  > /C:string  Uses specified string as a literal search string
  > ```

.

Comment: @Raymo111 ... I will assume you are familiar enough with batch to figure out the trivial stuff to further expand on my answer such as setting variables and using those in the correlated parts of the for loop, etc. I'm happy to help further assist should you require it and this detail not suffice for your needs. As I understand, you are simply looking for a solution that works and can fine tune from there. Getting overly complex with batch is simple to do, so when you get to that point with a task, consider switching to and learning to tackle the task with PowerShell. Good luck!!

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! Your solution does work, but is there a way to recurse through a directory and its subfolders with a `findstr` option?

P.S. Can't readonly be one word?

Comment: @Raymo111 - FINDSTR ought to be able to recurse a directory tree with the `/S` option. But there is a nasty bug that can cause some files to be skipped if your filesystem has short names enabled. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8844873/1012053 for more info. Look for the section header "BUG - Short 8.3 filenames can break the /D and /S options" within that answer.

Comment: /D wasn't getting subdirectories recursively, so I replaced it with a /R and moved some params around; that did the trick. I've edited your answer but I think it's only visible to me until it gets approved. Anyhow you should see it updated soon! Stay warm :)

Comment: Oh nos. I seem to have made my entire folder with thousands of files in it each one readonly. :notlikeblob: Edit: well I just went through and undid that with the same batch file, but `-r` :) Err my edit to your answer was terrible then, sorry about that :/ But why is /D not recursing?

Comment: hmmm still not working for some reason. Did you try more text  in the file than just the readonly comment? (for context these are C header files (.h) that have code in them with this comment near (but not at) the top.

Comment: I'm using the batch logic. I fatally forgot to note that all the files containing this comment end in `LF` (Unix style).

Comment: @Raymo111 Sorry about that, try the updated batch script logic, I failed to use double percent `%%` signs in a couple places. I tested with `LF` EOL files and it worked too. It was my mistake on the logic that was making the batch script hose up on you. Give it another shot when you get a chance after looking at the edit I just made and let me know how it goes.

Comment: Updated version marks all files in the directory readonly again :/

Comment: I'll do you one better. Here's a YouTube video in glorious 4k demonstrating the issue I'm facing (the high-def version might take a few minutes to process): https://youtu.be/UgBMCAgPgqU

Comment: @Raymo111 That was perfect and identified the problem very easily getting the visual. Thank you for that! I just adjusted the answer and using `findstr C:"// _READONLY_"` for literal without escaping the forward slashes. It appears the other way was matching the files that contained the `//` so using that seems to fix that. Please refresh and try the latest edit and see how that goes now.

Comment: Ayyyy now it works. One last thing is I'd add a note that your answer only searches txt files; I have to remove the `.txt` to search all files. But thanks for your help! Accepted and upvoted.